# How to enable title bar in Cordova Application?

Tags: html, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

Below is my code... I was not able to enable Title bar in my application.
How to enable that ?
config.xml

```
<widget id="com.example.hello" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <preference name="loglevel" value="DEBUG" />
    <feature name="Whitelist">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.whitelist.WhitelistPlugin" />
        <param name="onload" value="true" />
    </feature>
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    <name>HelloWorld</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
</widget>
```

I tried this..

```
<preference name="Fullscreen" value="false">
```

but its not working... Still the activity is displayed in fullscreen mode... How to disable that fullscreen and show title bar ?

Answer (score 2):

Add these two lines in config file

```
 preference name="fullscreen" value="false"
 preference name="showtitle" value="true"
```